# How to change the form of fraction

Tags: output-formatting, output

One of my output result is

```
(2 Sqrt[2/5])/3
```

Is there any method to let it become

```
Sqrt[8/45]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can  try `Defer[Sqrt][#^2] &[(2*Sqrt[2/5])/3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have same `LeafCount`.

[image]

Also  Mathematica will automatically write `Sqrt[8/45]` as `(2 Sqrt[2/5])/3`  So the following trick will not even work

```
t[e_] := e^2
res = Simplify[(2 Sqrt[2/5])/3,TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But now `Sqrt[res]` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There might be a trick using `Hold` or `HoldForm` but I could not figure it out. But even if this would work, once you release the Hold it will go back to `(2 Sqrt[2/5])/3`

Mathematica seems to like to put integer fraction inside the sqrt into its lowest common multiplier by pulling factors outside.

Comment: Perhaps a general replacement rule such as `/.Sqrt[#1]Sqrt[#2]:>Sqrt[#1 #2]` combined with `HoldForm` or even `Inactive`?

Comment: All right, thank you very much!